# Macro is failing on special characters from mailitem.Subject item (Run-time error '1004': Application-Defined or Object-Defined error)

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a macro that will import specific email items from my inbox and everything works perfect until it breaks at the email with subject line "=?ANSI_X3.4-1968?Q?......".

It seems like the email was originally written in other language and somehow it gets converted into a block of special characters that macro can't recognize. Please see the code below. Your helps will be highly appreciated!

sub search_inbox()

```
Range("A2:D60").ClearContents

Dim ol as Outlook.Application
Dim ns as Outlook.Namespace
Dim fol as Outlook.Folder
Dim i as Object
Dim mi as Outlook.MailItem
Dim rh as Double
Dim START_DATE as Date
Dim x as Long

Dim sh as Worksheet
set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")

set ol = New Outlook.Application
set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
set fol = ns.Folders(sh.Range("M1").value).Folders(sh.Range("M2").value)

START_DATE = sh.range("J8") + sh.range("J9")
END_DATE = sh.range("K8") + sh.range("K9")

for Each i in fol.items

    if i.SentOn >= START_DATE And i.SentOn <= END_DATE And i.Class = olMail Then
    
        n = n + 1
    
        set mi = i

        Cells(n+1, 1).Value = mi.SenderName
        Cells(n+1, 2).Value = mi.Subject
        Cells(n+1, 3).Value = mi.SenderEmailAddress
        Cells(n+1, 4).Value = mi.ReceivedTime
        Cells(n+1, 5).Value = mi.Categories
        Cells(n+1, 6).Value = mi.Size

    Else

    End If

    Next i

    MsgBox (x - 1)
```

End Sub

Comment: Under tools-> reference, i did enable "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" and re run the macro but still no luck. It breaks right at the " Cells(n+1, 2).Value = mi.Subject" line. Is there anyway to tweak it to bypass any special character in subject line? or rather to make it works regardless what characters being contained in subject line? Thanks

Comment: Try `Cells(n+1, 2).Value = CStr(mi.Subject)`. If this fails, create a variable of String type (failing which, of Variant type) and assign mi.Subject to that variable. Then examine the variable character by character to see what's causing the problem. The theory is, if you can assign mi.Subject to a VBA variable you can also assign it to a cell value, either in its existing form or after manipulation. But if you want to manipulate you have to know what you are looking for.

Comment: I did try your suggestion above but still no luck. when you said "then examine the variable character by character to see what's causing the problem", I am not 100% sure how to interpret that into vba. Can you specify that into lines of codes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The procedure below first creates a test string `Subject` and then analyses it. It looks at every character in turn. If it's a double width character it replaces it with a question mark. Finally, it issues a few message boxes about the result.

```
Private Sub FindSpecials()
    ' 262

    Dim Subject     As String           ' test string
    Dim Result      As String           ' Message string
    Dim Char        As String           ' one character of Subject
    Dim n           As Integer          ' loop counter: characters
    Dim Revised     As String           ' Subject without special characteres
    
    Subject = "Email about " & ChrW(19978) & ChrW(28023) & " traffic"
    For n = 1 To Len(Subject)
        Char = Mid(Subject, n, 1)
        If Asc(Char) <> AscW(Char) Then
            Result = Result & vbCr & "Character " & AscW(Char) & " = " _
                     & Char & " in position " & n
            Revised = Left(Subject, n - 1) & "?" & Mid(Subject, n + 1)
        End If
    Next n
    
    If StrComp(Subject, Revised) Then
        MsgBox "The following special characters were found" & Result
        MsgBox "This is the revised subject:" & vbCr & _
               """" & Revised & """"
    Else
        MsgBox "No double-width characters were found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Applied to your project, the test string `Subject` should be created from `mi.Subject`, of course. The output `Result` can be discarded but the string `Revised` might be useful to you. Of course, you might replace the double width characters with something other than a question mark. My code just intends to demonstrate how the special characters can be extracted and replaced.